# Can I replace a shared library's dependencies with static versions?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, wrapper

I have an application that depends upon a C++ shared library `libfoo.so`. I don't have source code to `libfoo.so`, only header files describing its interface and the shared library file itself. `libfoo.so` was linked to contain `libbar.so.1` as a dependency. My application also uses `libbar.so`, but it uses an ABI-incompatible revision `libbar.so.2`.

To recap, here's a rough hierarchy of the dependencies:

```
- myapp
    - libbar.so.2
    - libfoo.so
        - libbar.so.1
```

This setup causes problems, because I get multiply-defined symbols from the two `libbar` versions. `libbar` is an open-source library, and I have its static library `libbar.a.1` available.

Is it possible to modify or wrap `libfoo.so` in such a way that it no longer depends upon `libbar.so.1` at runtime? Specifically, I thought about doing something like this:

- Create a wrapper shared library `libfoowrapper.so` that links in `libfoo.so` and the static library `libbar.a.1`.
- Somehow hide the symbols from `libbar.a.1` so they don't get exported from `libfoowrapper.so`.
- Somehow eliminate the runtime dependency between `libfoowrapper.so` and its second-level dependency `libbar.so.1`.

Is this possible? I'm currently using `gcc` on Unix-like systems (Linux, MacOS), while I may have to to this for Windows using Visual Studio in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to modify or wrap libfoo.so in such a way that it no longer depends upon libbar.so.1 at runtime?

No: most UNIX systems (with exception of AIX) consider a `.so` *final* link product. No further modification is possible.

You do have a few options:

- Ask your "vendor" of `libfoo.so` to give you a more up-to-date copy that depends on `libbar.so.2`. This is the best solution.
- Don't depend on `libfoo.so` directly, but instead dynamically load it with `dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_LOCAL);`. The `RTLD_LOCAL` part will ensure that `libfoo.so` lives in a separate linker namespace, and that symbols from `libbar.so.1` are not used by anything other than `libfoo.so`.